# Festival audio device problems. No sound output

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

I currently have festival 2.4 installed and configured.

Heres what I'm doing:

I first use `./bin/festival` to get into the festival prompt.
Then do `(SayText "test")` which should have the tts speak the word test

Now when I have festival 2.1 installed using apt-get from the repository this command works as expected, it says "test"
However when running from manually-built festival 2.4 it reports no error, but also no sound. I have used set parameter commands and tried every audio method, also tried the set parameter command with `Audio_Device` and tried many of the devices from /dev/ and /dev/snd/ on my system to no avail.

Note that oss-compat is installed, I saw that listed as a solution somewhere and it was already installed from when I built cmu sphinx a while back.

My question is what is apt-get doing that I'm not. I've been at this for about 12 hours now so any ideas are welcome.

**Update**: I have used strace to monitor the calls festival is making to the system in an attempt to find out whats causing this, heres what I've come up with:

My system has multiple audio deivces connected to it, the integrated audio on the motherboard which is fried, the hdmi outputs of the nvidia card, and a usb audio device I'm using for the time being. `ls /dev/` shows three audio devices, as expected `/dev/audio`, `/dev/audio2`, and `/dev/audio3`. Setting festival to use the first two with `(Parameter.set 'Audio_Device "/dev/audio")` did the same thing as before, no error but also no sound. However when using the third device `/dev/audio3` I get `Linux: can't open /dev/audio3` upon further investigation with aforementioned strace I discovered this:

`open("/dev/audio3", O_WRONLY)           = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)`

I searched around a bit and the only mentions of this error I can find are for specialized cases for whatever the person in question was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to configure Pulseaudio. Add these lines to the end of your `~/.festivalrc` file, or to `/usr/share/festival/festival.scm`:

```
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Required_Format 'aiff)
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Method 'Audio_Command)
(Parameter.set 'Audio_Command "paplay $FILE --client-name=Festival --stream-name=Speech")
```

Comment: Yes I did this after you commented earlier, works like a charm!

Comment: In case you have multiple sound sinks (like an HDMI output) and fail to get sound, just add --device=0 or --device=1 to the last command.
ex: (Parameter.set 'Audio_Command "paplay --device=0 $FILE --client-name=Festival --stream-name=Speech")
Use "pacmd list-sinks" to identify the appropriate sink.

Comment: It just makes a weird hissing sound now, although it does come from the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. Armed with the information from strace It was only a matter of tracking down what was blocking my access to my audio devices.

`fuser -fv /dev/snd/* /dev/dsp* /dev/audio*`  will effectively show you anything accessing any audio device on your system. It showed that `pulseaudio` was accessing `/dev/snd/control****`, not audio3 but still worth a try. Then I ran `pulseaudio -k` to kill pulseaudio. After that I can hear festival.

Comment: The proper solution is to configure Festival to use pulseaudio instead https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Festival

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev If only you had told me that many hours ago ha ha. Now it works much better and I don't have to close other applications to make it work. Thank you very much Nikolay!